# Search Bar for UITableView: I would like it to search through both textLabels and detailTextLabels (iOS 5.0, xcode 4.2)

Tags: objective-c, ios4, ios5

I have set up a search bar for my table view, and I would like to have it search through both the textLabels (main text), and detailTextLabels (underlying text), while maintaining the relationship between the main labels and detail labels when narrowing down the search.  Right now, I can search through the main labels only, but the detail labels will not stay with the related main labels.  I have two arrays that carry the strings for the main labels and the detail labels.  Here is some code.

The initialization of the arrays carrying the main labels (groceryStores) and the detail labels (groceryStoreAddresses), as well as the search array

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.groceryStores = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Safeway",@"Grocery Store 1",@"Grocery Store 2",@"Grocery Store 3",@"Grocery Store 4",@"Grocery Store 5",@"Grocery Store 6",@"Grocery Store 7",nil];

    self.groceryStoreAddresses = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1444 Shattuck Place, Berkeley, CA   94709",@"Address 1",@"Address 2",@"Address 3",@"Address 4",@"Address 5",@"Address 6",@"Address 7",nil];

    self.searchGroceryStores = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[self.groceryStores count]];


}
```

The search method

```
 - (BOOL) searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString {
    [self.searchGroceryStores removeAllObjects] ;

    for (NSString *groceryStore in self.groceryStores) {



        NSRange result = [groceryStore rangeOfString:searchString options:
                          NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
        if (result.location != NSNotFound)
            [self.searchGroceryStores addObject:groceryStore];

    }

    return YES;
}
```

Rows in section tweaked for search functionality

```
  - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        return [self.searchGroceryStores count];
    }
    else {

    return [self.groceryStores count];
    }
}
```

cellForRowAtIndexPath tweaked for search functionality

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator"];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;        

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [self.searchGroceryStores objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [self.groceryStoreAddresses objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    else {
        cell.textLabel.text = [self.groceryStores objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [self.groceryStoreAddresses objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}
```

Please help if you can.  Thank you so much for your time, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep a `searchGroceryStoreAddresses` array in parallel with your `searchGroceryStores` array.  Example:

```
- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString {
    [self.searchGroceryStores removeAllObjects];
    [self.searchGroceryStoreAddresses removeAllObjects];
    for (int i = 0, c = self.groceryStores.count; i < c; ++i) {
        NSString *groceryStore = [self.groceryStores objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString *address = [self.groceryStoreAddresses objectAtIndex:i];
        NSRange result = [groceryStore rangeOfString:searchString options:
                          NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
        if (result.location != NSNotFound) {
            [self.searchGroceryStores addObject:groceryStore];
            [self.searchGroceryStoreAddresses addObject:address];
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I created a searchGroceryStoreAddresses array, but how do I implement it into my searchDisplayController method?  Everytime I try to add an && or || statement to the for loop argument, xcode results in an error.

Comment: I'm still having trouble finding out how to keep the two arrays in parallel with each other.  How do I ensure that the objects at the same index in both arrays are synced with each other so that the correct detail Label appears with the corresponding text label?

Comment: I'm sorry Rob, but I'm not sure how to do that in my searchDisplayController method.  Could you give me a quick example with code?

Comment: Thank you Rob, this works beautifully.  Is there also a way where I can make it that the user can search by address too?  This solution works to keep the the correct addresses linked to the correct stores, but will not work if I search for an address (by city, etc..)

Comment: I'm sure the strings in your `groceryStoreAddresses` array respond to the `rangeOfString:options:` message the same way the strings in your `groceryStores` array do.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the code I used it in my project and it works great! But I would like to sort the data alphabetically on Stores and Addresses. Currently the order is only alphabetically on the Stores and not on the actual search hits. Can you help me out with this?

Comment: @Daniel Have you searched for "sort" in the `NSMutableArray` documentation?